# A certain confusion about notations such as $(h(gf))(x)=(hu)(x)$?

Tags: functions

I am a little confused about the following notation:

[image]

What is the meaning of each manipulation, I guessed the following:  We have a mapping $X \stackrel{f}{\to}X \stackrel{g}{\to}X \stackrel{h}{\to}X$, so when we do:

$$(h(gf))(x)=(hu)(x)$$

We are composing the maps $f,g$ in a new map $u$, instead of applying $f$ "directly" to an $x\in X$. Now:

$$h(u(x))$$

We apply $u$ in $x$ and:

$$h(g(f(x)))$$

As $u=gf$ and $g,f$ are bijections, $u$ must be unique which is what allow us to go back and forth from $u$ to $gf$.

$$v(f(x))$$

Seems to mean that - just as before - we can compose the maps $h,g$ into $v$ instead of applying it on a single element $f(x)$. Now:

$$(vf)(x)$$

Now we can "decompose" $f(x)$ into $(vf)(x)$ because independently of the chosen $x$ we have full information about what $f$ is, due to bijectivity.

$$((hg)f)(x)$$

And we can use that $v=hg$ for the same reason I pointed before. Is this correct? What I find particularly troubling is the transformation from $(f)(x)$ to $f(x)$, I explained what I think it might be, but I'm not perfectly sure about it. I have also thought that perhaps $(x)$ could represent the identity mapping, but I'm not sure if both meanings are equivalent nor which one of those are actually the intention of the author. This is perhaps a duplicate, but I couldn't really locate something analogous to this.

Answer (score 1):

*Equality of Functions:* Let $f,g: A \to B$ be two functions between two non-empty sets. We say $f$ and $g$ are equal, written $f=g$, if $f(x)=g(x), \forall x \in A.$

*Composition of Functions:* Let $f:A \to B, g: B\to C$ be two functions of non-empty sets. The *composition* of $f$ and $g$ is the function $u: A \to C$ defined by $u(x)=g(f(x)),$ for each $x \in A$. This function is usually denoted by $g \circ f$ (or simply by $gf$). So with this notation, $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$ for each $x \in A$.

Now let's go though the proof:

We are given $X\xrightarrow{f}X\xrightarrow{g}X\xrightarrow{h}X$. We want to show $(h\circ g)\circ f= h\circ(g\circ f)$, in other words, $((h\circ g)\circ f)(x)=(h\circ(g\circ f))(x), \forall x \in X$.

Let's denote the function $g\circ f : X \to X$ by $u$, and $h\circ g: X \to X$ by $v$. Then $$u(y)=(g\circ f)(y)=g(f(y)), \forall y \in X$$ and $$v(y)=(h\circ g)(y)=h(g(y)), \forall y\in X.$$

Fix $x\in X$. Then $$((h\circ g)\circ f)(x)=(v\circ f)(x)=v(f(x))=h(g(f(x)))$$
using the description of $v$. Similarly $$(h\circ (g\circ f))(x)=(h\circ u)(x)=h(u(x))=h(g(f(x)))$$ using the definition of $u$. But this is true for every $x\in X$. Hence we have the required equality.